# Extract a list of users from a text file

Tags: python, parsing, file

```
fo=open("haproxyfile.txt","r")
users=[]
for lines in fo.readlines():
    if 'user' and 'password' in lines:
        items=lines.split() #converts to list"""
        users.append(items[1]) #append the second item that is the username"""

print users
```

**The content of haproxyfile.txt is below**

```
ssl-default-bind-ciphers EECDH+EDSA+ACM:CDH+aRSA+AEdfGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EEC+
ESA+SHA:EDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EDH:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-S
HA:EDH+SA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES-SHA256:AES256-SHA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3D:!MD5:!EXP:
!PSK:!SRP:!DSS

        # Users
        userlist IntacctAdmins
          group admins users aasghar,achouchoulas,bwright,calla,gspiliotis,haris,pdam
          user aasghar password $1$CFdTKLSRSbQME/
          user achouchoulas password $1$uLy//uPCaVSNhfFG/
          user bwright password $1$q3Fk$kmqM.J531
          user calla password $1$f%g23a44$Bl.1fPj/
          user gspiliotis password $1$d/2OI.TQOiV1
          user haris password $1$mwQ$uG/1mUjE0
          user pdam password $1t24Z$K4FUH/
```

**What I need to parse from the content**

The line after having the words **groups** are the lines where my user names are located. They are the single words after user keyword.I have fetched it using the method above.Is there any better way to fetch it?

Comment: The file should be a little better specified, imo. For example, the way it currently looks, you could potentially just split the `group admins users` line by commas. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few possible improvements.

You should open files with the [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) keyword, this way they get closed no matter what (you don't even close your file).

`if 'user' and 'password' in lines:` does not mean what you think it does. All non-empty strings are truthy in Python, so `if "user"` is always `True`. So you only really check that the line contains `"password"`. Fortunately you don't have any lines containing `"password"`, but not `"users"`, so this bug has not yet become obvious.

The easiest fix for this would be using this:

```
if "user" in lines and "password" in lines:
    # Stuff
```

In summary, I would re-write your code like this:

```
with open("haproxyfile.txt") as f:
    users = [line.split()[1] for line in f 
             if line.strip().startswith("user") and "password" in line]

print users
```

Note that I omitted the `"r"` parameter to `open`, because read-only is the default mode. I also used [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to check if it starts with a string. The `strip` is probably needed, to get rid of the whitespace at the beginning of your lines. If that is a copy&paste error as well, omit it.

I also wrote it as a [list-comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) and used the fact that you can directly iterate over a file.

Comment: I am checking the line has user and password on it ,user aasghar password $1$CFdTKLSRSbQME/ as this lines has the both

Comment: @TaraGurung No, `if 'user' and 'password' in lines` is the same as `if True and 'password' in lines`, which is the same as `if 'password' in lines`. You either want to do it like I do (which uses the extra information that "user" is the first word), or do `if "user" in lines and "password" in lines` or `if all(x in lines for x in ["user", "password"])`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what your code does or how it works.  I have to figure out what the result of `lines.split()` looks like, and what `items[1]` represents — and all I have to go by, according to the code, is that the lines of interest contain the word `'password'`.

I recommend doing it a completely different way, using regular expression matching, so that it is obvious what kind of text pattern you expect to extract.  I would also write it using a list comprehension, so that the `users` list is defined declaratively, "all at once".

```
import re

with open('haproxyfile.txt') as f:
    users = [
        match.group(1) for match in (
            re.search(r'^\s*user\s+(\S+)\s+password', line) for line in f
        )
        if match
    ]

print users
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't passwords be coded?  If passwords are not coded-could it put user privacy and/or administrator settings at risk?

Comment: The passwords look encrypted for me. Or what did you mean?

Comment: Did you mean encrypted instead?

Comment: @Graipher It looks like a real attempt to answer to me, not a good one though. [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264293/why-shouldnt-i-delete-wrong-answers)

Comment: @Simon Fair enough, but I do agree with panta rei that the passwords do look encrypted/hashed, which made me think of this like more of a question asking for clarification when I saw it in the review queue.